# Not getting email from facebook API while login

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I have a problem while login i can't get email even while adding email to User & Friend Permissions (for some facebook accounts).

i'm using facebook-php-sdk, this the code that im using

`$facebook_user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'id,email,first_name,last_name,picture'));`

please can any one save my day ?

Comment: The permissions you set in the app dashboard are for direct access from the app center only. If you do login yourself, you have to ask for permissions using the `scope` parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Comment: thx for the link i'm using now `Facebook::getLoginUrl` and asking for email permission with scope.

Answer (score 15):

Apart from what CBroe commented about asking for the permissions using the "scope" parameter while logging in to grab [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions), you must also consider the fact that not every logged in user (or a user allowing your application to access their info) has an email assigned to their account.

one can verify their facebook accounts using their Mobile numbers, hence the probability that no email exists. Therefore, when developing an application, take into consideration if a user does not have an email, then you should ask for it manually through a form after login (this is IF the email is necessary for users to use your app).

hope this info helps!

Comment: actually yes, the app that i'm developing necessite email, but i should take consideration your clarification about users not allowing access their info or users don't have e-mail.

Comment: glad i was able to help

Comment: @Amjo  I am following http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/ . can you please tell me where to include FB.login() function  after downloading their source code?

Comment: @partho FB.login() is actually part of the Facebook JavaScript API. The link you provided is a detailed guide to implementing FB login using PHP. These two are separate approaches; therefore, you should understand I'm a little confused with your question. for details on how to implement the FB Javascript API, their documentation is pretty detailed and informative right here: [FB.login()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.4)

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs when you have made the Facebook account with an email address and have not confirmed the email to be used by Facebook. As soon as you approve from your email, the Facebook login will return the email address.

Hope this solves the issue.