# How to get user email from facebook api user after Login

Tags: php, facebook

I have an issue with using the facebook api to retrieve user email address from facebook after the user login, i have viewed many post related to this on stackoverflow, but not still able to solve my problem

**Links viewed**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828849/i-cant-get-user-email-address-on-facebook

[I cant get user email address on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828849/i-cant-get-user-email-address-on-facebook)

This is my code

```
require 'facebook.php';

 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $client_id,
  'secret' => $client_secret,
));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user_profile);
        echo "</pre>";

      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
      }
    } else {
      die('<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>');
    }

        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'         => 'email, read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos'
        ));

    echo $user_profile['email'];
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

other information i need is displayed except for email address

Comment: You have to request email permission before access to email is granted.

Comment: i thought i had already done that in this line ?                  'scope'=> 'email, read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos'

Comment: Maybe, but it depends on what you do with $loginUrl. Can you publish a more complete source code?

Comment: Thanks but actually, thats all the code i have, i just simply want to retrieve the email address and display it, and thats all

Comment: Then you're not fully understanding how FB API works. Login URL has to be used to redirect the user to Facebook to request her permission for the requested permissions. After that, Facebook redirects it to your page to proceed again. In the sample you linked, key points are the `if ($user)` at the top (check you really have the user info) and the `echo "<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>";` at the bottom (to redirect to FB if you don't). Also keep in mind that the used may grant access to FB but not permission to access her email address.

Comment: yea, i guess i understand now, but i still have an issue where browser actually bypasses the if($user) check, Unless i clear my cache...any help around that ?

Comment: Probably a problem with your web server configuration, but cannot say for sure.